# Can a Dell Latitude E6440 support Quad Display?

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude

I've found the more monitors I have running on my work computer, the better I can do my job. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to get a Latitude E6440 to display on 4 screens (3 external + the laptop). The graphics card is an Intel HD Graphics 4600 if that matters. I've only been able to figure out how to get 3 displays running (laptop + 2 external, or just 3 external). Is it possible to get all 4 screens up and running? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In all cases Intel HD Graphics 4600 supports a maximum of *three* monitors.

Your laptop may have one of several models of CPU but, for arguments sake, here are the [specifications](http://ark.intel.com/products/80345/Intel-Core-i7-4610M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz) for the i7 CPU:

Now the laptop's built-in display counts as one display, so that leaves a maximum of two external displays.

If you must have a 4th display, you can purchase a USB display adapter which will work with Windows 7 onwards:

http://www.displaylink.com/products/usb-adapters